# Flatten subfolders matlab

Tags: matlab, directory

I have the following problem: I have a folder (root folder) that contains a lot of files and subfolders. Each subfolder contains a number of files (of any type). I want to flatten all the subfolders to have the root folder that contains the files that were previously stored in the subfolders.
For example I have: 
Main_folder
    File1
    File2
    Subfolder1
        File3
    Subfolder2
        File4

I want to obtain:
Main_folder
   File1
   File2
   File3
   File4

Is there a way to do that automatically in Matlab?

Comment: What's your environment? Windows? Mac? Linux? For Mac/Linux, I would do this with a bash shell script. This isn't really what Matlab is for...

Comment: There are literally thousands of ways to do this with various tools...

Comment: ok, can you please tell me one method? Don't you know any matlab way to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this in MATLAB using a combination of `dir` to get a directory listing, `fullfile` to construct paths, `movefile` to move the files to their new place.

**First run the following script on a *copy* of your data in case it has any issues**

```
function flattenFolder(folder, destination)
    if ~exist('destination', 'var')
        destination = folder;
    end

    %// Get a list of everything in this folder
    D = dir(folder);

    %// Grab just the directories and remove '.' and '..'
    folders = {D([D.isdir]).name};
    folders = folders(~ismember(folders, {'.', '..'}));

    %// Get all the files
    files = {D(~[D.isdir]).name};

    %// Remove .DS_store files
    files = files(~strcmpi(files, '.DS_store'));

    %// For every subfolder, call this function recursively
    for k = 1:numel(folders)
        flattenFolder(fullfile(folder, folders{k}), destination);
    end

    %// If the source and destination are the same, don't worry about moving the files
    if strcmp(folder, destination)
        return
    end

    %// Move all of the files to the destination directory
    for k = 1:numel(files)

        destfile = fullfile(destination, files{k});

        %// Append '_duplicate' to the filename until the file doesn't exist
        while exist(destfile, 'file')
            [~, fname, ext] = fileparts(destfile);  
            destfile = fullfile(destination, sprintf('%s_duplicate%s', fname, ext));
        end

        movefile(fullfile(folder, files{k}), destfile);
    end 
end
```

Then with your example you would call this as:

```
flattenFolder('Main_Folder')
```

**Note**

As others have said, MATLAB isn't the ideal tool for this task. Since you're on OS X, using bash from the command line may be a better option.

```
find Main_Folder/ -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv -i '{}' Main_Folder/ ';'
```

Comment: well, thank you, it is a really great solution and it works perfectly. Just another thing: do you have any idea regarding how to do this control: if while moving each file in the Main_Folder you find a file with the same name, rename the file you are moving adding for example the 'w' letter at the end of the file the system is moving? Thank you very much

Comment: @David I have modified it to add `_duplicate` to a file that is already present in the destination.

Comment: I've tried to run the code with the modification you've done but I get the following error (I have in the folders the hidden files .DS_Store):

Comment: Error using movefile
mv: rename
/Users/Solbia/Desktop/prova/Pet_Total_Body/_duplicate.DS_Store to
/Users/Solbia/Desktop/provaout/_duplicate.DS_Store: No such file
or directory
Error in flattenFolder (line 35)
        movefile(fullfile(folder, files{k}), ...
Error in flattenFolder (line 18)
        flattenFolder(fullfile(folder, folders{k}),
        destination);
Error in flattenFolder (line 18)
        flattenFolder(fullfile(folder, folders{k}),
        destination);
Error in flattenFolder (line 18)
        flattenFolder(fullfile(folder, folders{k}),
        destination);

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You're genius. Thank you very much, I really do appreciate that. It works perfectly now.